# TestCafe: extending &#39;expect&#39; to incorporate jest-image-snapshot

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, testcafe, visual-testing, jest-image-snapshot

I noticed that there was an option to extend Selector for TestCafe.  The project I am working on needs to have Visual Image Testing.

I wanted to see if I could get `jest-image-snapshot` working with conjunction with TestCafe...but failing to do so.

So, need help in understanding how I can incorporate that package into validation of a screenshot taken during TestCafe.

here is some basic code I wrote so far:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
```

const { toMatchImageSnapshot } = require('jest-image-snapshot');
var fs = require('fs');

fixture('Snapshots').page('https://tallkurideon.myshopify.com/');

```
test('check something here', async (t) => {
    expect.extend({ toMatchImageSnapshot })
    // then pass the `t` reference to invoke the helper
    const image = fs.readFile('./test-results/Snapshots/Catalog__chrome/base.png')
    await t.expect(image).toMatchImageSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe doesn't use the jest `expect` API, and the `t.expect` method cannot be extended. I suggest you try the [looks-same](https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same) library instead of `jest-image-snapshot`. You can take a screenshot with the `t.takeScreenshot()` or `t.takeElementScreenshot(selector)` method and compare them with a local image file. See this documentation topic: [Take Screenshot](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/take-screenshot.html).